# How to make m2e-android include native deps for apk packaging?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

A follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506624/sensibility-of-combined-maven-antivy-build-management-for-dual-platform-desktop). I'm using libgdx, and hence have added (among others) the following deps to my POM, as per [this wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/NativeLibsAsDependencies):

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.badlogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>libgdx-armeabi-gdx</artifactId>
            <version>${libgdx.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>so</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.badlogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>libgdx-armeabi-androidgl20</artifactId>
            <version>${libgdx.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>so</type>
        </dependency>
```

where `libgdx.version` is a property I set in the POM (currently at 0.9.3, all artifacts are loaded in the repo, the libgdx native loading sequence is changed to account for the non-standard filenames, etc.).

Here's the problem: I'm using ADT in Eclipse with the m2e-android connector, and *when I launch the project from ADT*, it fails to finds these native libraries in the APK.

On the other hand, *if I launch using the appropriate Maven goals*, the APK builds fine, with those .so libraries correctly placed in lib/armeabi.

Is this a deficiency in the current version of m2e-android (I did notice some bugs on GitHub, but those were related to NDK development, not native dependencies per se), and 
**I just have to wait for a new version? Or can I add something to my POM that will cause m2e-android to "see" those deps?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, m2e-android does not yet support native library dependencies. We are aware of the problem, and there are issues for these. We could directly implement support for native libraries directly:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/71

Or we could replace the ADT APK native builder, with a Maven APK builder:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/67

Patches and pull requests gratefully considered.

Comment: Just to clarify, a question regarding issue 71: it's the one I saw, and I thought it pertained only to NDK development *within* a project, as opposed to an external, pre-compiled, native dependency. Do I understand correctly it actually covers both cases?

Comment: I'm unsure, it could be both, or you can open a separate issue for native library dependencies. Either way, probably better to request new features on the m2e-android issue tracker, or ask a question on the mailing list then post a question on SO.

Comment: Sure, I wasn't certain about the nature of the issue 'though. Regarding the mailing list, the links pointed to the general maven-android plugin group, this coupled with a chance observation that you are active on SO caused me to post here. And finally, about contributing code - I actually accidentally forked the project yesterday, so I *might* do just that :).

Comment: I do post here, but I only pop here on and off whereas I'm constantly monitoring the maven-android-developers mailing list, and I get instantly notified whenever someone raises a ticket on Github. Nice of you to fork the project, let me know if you have any questions about the code.